# Subqueries are not allowed in this context -- SQL statement from 2008 to 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL statement which run in a window form application.
I am using SQL server 2008 to develop and test. Everything is alright here.

```
            SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("insert into payment_detail ( " +
                                                "transaction_id, enrolment_id, hkid_1, section_r, " +
                                                "classes, section_fee, assist_amt, additional_assist_amt, " +
                                                "discount_amt, coupon_amt, coupon_amt_no_number, " +
                                                "paid_amt, last_updated_by, last_updated_date) values " +
                                                "(@transaction_id, @enrolment_id, @hkid_1, @section_r, " +
                                                "@classes, @section_fee, (select section_fee - adjusted_section_fee from coursenew where coursecode = @courseCode and section_r = @section_r), @additional_assist_amt, " +
                                                "@discount_amt, @coupon_amt, @coupon_amt_no_number, " +
                                                "@paid_amt, @last_updated_by, GETDATE())"
                                                , myConnection);
```

But when moving to another work station which is using SQL server 2005.
It prompts out an error like below

Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

I am sorry that since a computer can only install one version of SQL server.
I cannot test the script with a SQL server 2005.

Please help and thanks.

For the full sql statement will be listed below

```
 insert into payment_detail ( transaction_id, enrolment_id, hkid_1, section_r, classes, section_fee, assist_amt, additional_assist_amt, discount_amt, coupon_amt, coupon_amt_no_number, paid_amt, last_updated_by, last_updated_date) values (@transaction_id, @enrolment_id, @hkid_1, @section_r, @classes, @section_fee, (select section_fee - adjusted_section_fee from coursenew where coursecode = @courseCode and section_r = @section_r), @additional_assist_amt, @discount_amt, @coupon_amt, @coupon_amt_no_number, @paid_amt, @last_updated_by, GETDATE())"
```

Comment: I'm a bit lazy, but if you edit your SQL statement (remove all " and , + etc, and format it nicely), I'll look at it.

Comment: "since a computer can only install one version of SQL server" - I don't know why you believe that to be true, but it's not. My current machine is running 3 different instances of SQL Server, all on different versions. Currently running 2008, 2012 and 2014, but I've been running such mixes as far back as a 2000, 2005 and 2008 install.

Comment: ops.
Do you mean install different version directly or some setup are needed to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn it into a query that inserts from a select instead uf using a subquery:

```
insert into payment_detail (
  transaction_id, enrolment_id, hkid_1, section_r, classes, section_fee,
  assist_amt,
  additional_assist_amt, discount_amt, coupon_amt, coupon_amt_no_number,
  paid_amt, last_updated_by, last_updated_date
)
select
  @transaction_id, @enrolment_id, @hkid_1, @section_r, @classes, @section_fee,
  section_fee - adjusted_section_fee,
  @additional_assist_amt, @discount_amt, @coupon_amt, @coupon_amt_no_number,
  @paid_amt, @last_updated_by, GETDATE()
from
  coursenew
where
  coursecode = @courseCode and section_r = @section_r
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply first.
This is the first time for me to see the query in this style.
But does it work in SQL 2005?

Comment: @user3423149 - it's valid even as far back as [SQL Server 2000](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) (see example G).

Comment: let me implement it to the working station.
If it works, I will mark up as answer later.
Thanks for your big help

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way around this is to put your select statement into a local variable before running your insert, and then use your temporary table in place of the sub-query.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx

Edit: specific example of selecting into a local variable.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's because your sub query does return more than **one** scalar value.
It does not related to version of SQLServer and is a logical problem.
write it as bellow :

```
select TOP 1 section_fee - adjusted_section_fee from coursenew where coursecode = @courseCode and section_r = @section_r
```

Comment: Not really bro.
The coursecode and the section_r are the key of the table coursenew

It works in my SQL server 2008 but not in 2005

Comment: No, it's not because of multiple values, it's actually a limitation in the `insert` statement in SQL Server 2005. "The expression cannot contain a SELECT or EXECUTE statement" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28v=sql.90%29.aspx